# How to hide admin menu generate by plugins in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, hide

Recently i have installed two plugins in my site. The plugins generate two admin menu. I wanna hide these menu.

Menu name are :

**WP Metaboxer** Mouse hover link (mysite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=mtbxr_metabox)

**BWS Plugins** Mouse hover link (mysite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=bws_plugins)

I can hide other default menu by these code

```
function remove_admin_menu_items() {
  $remove_menu_items = array(__('Media'),__('Links'), __('Comments'), __('Tools'), __('Appearance'), __('Posts'),__('Settings'),__('Plugins')));
  global $menu;
  end ($menu);
  while (prev($menu)){
    $item = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
    if(in_array($item[0] != NULL?$item[0]:"" , $remove_menu_items)){
      unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
    }
  }
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_items');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following at the bottom of remove_admin_menu_items:

```
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=mtbxr_metabox' );
remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=bws_plugins' );
```

then change the priority of your action to run last:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_items', 9999);
```

Comment: First one success but BWS Plugins menu not hide. I have tried with remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=bws_plugins' );

Comment: I have tried it also but remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=mtbxr_metabox' ); works remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=bws_plugins' ); Not works

Comment: but did you change the priority for the action to 9999?

Comment: Finall i have fixed it by this remove_menu_page( 'bws_plugins' );

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answer. I had the same issues.
To remove a plugin menu item, just by name you can check the structure of the URL.

For instance, Visual Composer has: */admin.php?page=**vc-general***

`remove_menu_page( 'vc-general' );`
`remove_menu_page( 'revslider' );`
`remove_menu_page( 'bws_plugins' );`

Answer (score 0):

Some Plugins add the menu item as submenu items, so you have to use the following function.

```
remove_submenu_page( 'options-general.php', 'disable-emails' );
```

here the WP-Reference for both functions:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_submenu_page/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_menu_page/